# List[String] -> Vector[Vector[Char]]

Tags: string, list, scala, vector, char

I am trying to convert a list of strings to a vector of char vectors:

```
import collection.breakOut

def stringsToCharVectors(xs: List[String]) =
    xs.map(stringToCharVector)(breakOut) : Vector[Vector[Char]]

def stringToCharVector(x: String) =
    x.map(a => a)(breakOut) : Vector[Char]
```

Is there a way to implement `stringToCharVector` that does not involve mapping with the identity function? Generally, are there shorter/better ways to implement `stringsToCharVectors`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a `String` directly to the varargs constructor for `Vector`:

```
def stringToCharVector(x: String) = Vector(x: _*)
```

at which point having a separate method seems kind of silly.  `breakOut` is for optimization; if you just want to convert, you can

```
Vector(xs.map(x => Vector(x: _*)): _*)
```

at the relatively modest expense of one extra object per list element.  (All the chars will most likely be the memory-intensive part.)

Comment: Thanks - this did what I wanted it to do.  But What does `x: _*` mean?  The colon after the x makes me expect a type to follow, but the underscore looks like the default variable and adding the star to that just makes my head spin.

Comment: `: _*` means "pass the elements of this collection as separate items into a method that takes varargs".  Since a string can be interpreted as a collection of characters, this works.

Answer (score 5):

In Scala 2.10:

```
scala> val xs = List("hello")
xs: List[String] = List(hello)

scala> xs.map(_.to[Vector]).to[Vector]
res0: Vector[Vector[Char]] = Vector(Vector(h, e, l, l, o))
```

Answer (score 1):

The other way is just to add all the elements to an empty Vector; this is what happens behind the scenes anyway when you call a conversion method:

```
def stringsToCharVectors(xs: List[String]) =
    Vector() ++ xs.map(Vector() ++ _)
```